# What's the widest character ever?

Tags: font, help

This doesn't have to be English, it could also be a symbol or some other language. I have not tried anything.

Comment: Define "longest": Most bytes to represent? Longest width relative to height in a standard font? Something else?

Comment: Can you add more context why are you exploring this. Validation check for some thing? Research? Deciding some UX?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with UX

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about the other language characters such as Chinese/Japanese but the widest character where the english alphabet is used must be upper case W. The widest number Is 8. Hope that helps!

Comment: This depends entirely on the font used, I once worked with one where the "4" was the widest number.